# An attitude of religious faith

Tags: meaning

> **An attitude *of* religious faith** is attractive to many people. It makes the kind of arguments we have been considering irrelevant. Yet
> at its most extreme, religious faith can make people completely blind
> to the evidence against their views: it can become more like
> stubbornness than a rational attitude.

I don't understand the meaning of the word "of" in the bold text. I think it means "showing"

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/of?q=of

Could you explain it to me? Thanks

Comment: I would go with definition 5 - 'describing what something consists of'.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, we would say someone has an attitude *to*, or *towards* something, as an attitude is a *disposition*. Also, "faith" isn't really an 'attitude', it is a belief. For example, you wouldn't say that someone has an "attitude of science".

However, in trying to understand what has been written, I would agree with comments that the use of "of" is to suggest that a specific attitude is *based upon* a religious belief. Whoever wrote it is probably trying to describe an attitude they think religious people have.